# WCF Abort Pattern - How To measure faulted connections

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

For some time i've issues in a webapi project which may be triggered by hanging ressources. The websites hangs and in a memory dump i can see that a lot of code is related to some WCF calls.

I've found some ressources like this [WCF Try Catch Abort Pattern Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/622989/WCF-and-the-Try-Catch-Abort-Pattern) from codeproject saying that under the descriped circumstances the wcf client should be arboted.

Like this:

```
try
{
    ...
    client.Close();
}
catch (CommunicationException e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
    throw;
}
```

Now is there a way to measure if there are connections not successfully closed ? I would like to see the changes before and after the code changes.

Are there perphas performance counters?

Comment: I do not think there is a WCF performance counter to tell how many open client connections are present at any given point in time. Here are the details of performance counters exposed by WCF : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx. If you are suspecting that memory is consumed by too many instances due to open connections, you may want to take a look at the "Instances" counter. Also, your question mentions that you are using webapi project, but your question appears to be about WCF performance counters. Can you please clarify whether you are using WCF or ASP .net web api?

Comment: I use a ASP Web Api as host, but one method of the api needs to consume a given third party WCF Service

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789041(v=vs.110).aspx - definitive explaination of ICommunicationObject workflow inclusing Abort(). Specifically, it states that calling Abort can result in an exception.